# Word for being the same externally yet different internally

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an word (adjective or noun) that describes the fact of two (or more) objects to be the same externally but different internally.

For example, how would you characterize the quality of two devices that perform the same function yet are intrinsically different when you examine them closer?

I am thinking of the word '*twin*', but I am not completely satisfied with it. Any ideas?

Example sentence:

> This mechanical system can be in two different states, yet undistinguishable for an external observer. One can cause the system to switch between these _______ states by applying a certain force...

Comment: Can you give the sentence where you would use the word?

Comment: @fev Example sentence:
'This mechanical system can be in two different states, yet undistinguishable for an external observer. One can cause the system to switch between these [insert sought adjective] states by applying a certain force...'

Comment: Not a single word: they are *superficially* the same.

Comment: Since the example sentence already makes the point, you could say *these **alternate** states*.

Comment: You already describe the states as *indistinguishable*, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Well, the two states are still distinguishable when you examine them closer; they are only undistinguishable for an external observer who only has access to limited information about those different states. I'd like to emphasize that by using only one word preferably.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure, you are right. But I'd like to use this word later in other sentences as well. The example sentence is just an example; I am more interested in finding a word that would capture the essence of 'being the same externally but different internally' in a general context. Thanks anyways for your input.

Comment: You can have multiple ***implementations / instantiations*** of both physical objects (tools, medicines, books,...)  AND abstract nouns (artistic performances, socio-political structures,...) that might ***look*** the same (however you define that) AND ***perform the same function*** (again, however *that's* defined). A crucial word in this context is [***fungibility***](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fungibility.asp) - which in recent years has extended its relevance far beyond the original domain-specific legal/financial sphere into areas like particle physics and philosophy.

Comment: In many technical contexts we might refer to any given implementation as a "black box" - where we don't know or care what's going on *inside*, so long as *this* black box performs exactly the same function as *that* black box.

Comment: 'Surface structure' and 'deep structure' are used in grammar. Two sentences may have the same surface structure but a different underlying structure.

Comment: I am curious about how the operator will know they have applied sufficient force to change the state, if the underlying state isn't apparent to them...

Comment: It might help if you explain in which context you imagine this being used. Is the fact of transitioning between states important? Can the two be differentiated by dismantling or looking in a window or not at all? Your example doesn't sound very much like a real-world device. Different disciplines like software engineering, quantum physics, product design, philosophy, and stage magic may have different terms for this. (For example, an electronic device which has been redesigned internally but has the same functionality, or a quantum physical system with indeterminate internal state.)

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a popular answer, but I'm going to say that there is probably *not a word for this*. It isn't a common situation, and where we *do* have a situation where two things look the same but are actually different, and we *need to talk about them*, we are likely to invent language for it (just as how quantum physicists invented nonsense like "red", "blue" and "strange" merely to differentiate things that aren't easy to tell apart in reality).

In a real conversation in English, you'd probably use a phrase like "only superficially alike".

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the two states are **(like) chalk and cheese**.

Here's *Wiktionary* defining the idiom:

> Said of things that very different, though possibly superficially alike.

*Etymology*

> Attested in variant form since 1393. The surface of some cheeses, particularly unaged ones, looks similar to chalk – white, crumbling – but in substance cheese is much softer than chalk

Answer (score -1):

Look alikes: [Freedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+alikes): 1. noun A person or thing that looks very similar to another person or thing. When used as a noun, the term is often hyphenated or spelled as one word.
2. verb To look very similar to another person or thing.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. A lookalike is the same on the outside, but it might be the same on the inside too.  The question asks for something that's the same on the outside but DIFFERENT inside.

Comment: It does answer the question. Identical means same externally and internally, look alike means "only looks are alike" which is external. If both external and internal were alike "identical"would be used, not "look alike". Kindly remove the negative vote.